# Correct and easy way convert JSON::PP::Boolean to 0,1 with perl

Tags: json, perl, yaml

Trying convert `JSON` to `YAML`. Have this code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;
use warnings;

use JSON;
use YAML;

my $json_string = q(
{
   "some" : [
      { "isFlagged" : true, "name" : "Some name" },
      { "isFlagged" : false, "name" : "Some other name" }
   ]
}
);

my $data = decode_json($json_string);
say Dump($data);
```

it produces:

```
---
some:
  - isFlagged: !!perl/scalar:JSON::PP::Boolean 1
    name: Some name
  - isFlagged: !!perl/scalar:JSON::PP::Boolean 0
    name: Some other name
```

I need convert the `JSON::PP::Boolean` objects to `0` or `1`. Of course, I could remove every `!!perl/scalar:JSON::PP::Boolean` string from the `YAML` output, but this doesn't seems to me as an correct solution.

So, what is the easy and correct way convert all `JSON::PP::Boolean` objects to simple `0` and `1`, so the `YAML` will generate

```
---
some:
  - isFlagged: 1
    name: Some name
  - isFlagged: 0
    name: Some other name
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use YAML's [Stringify option](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod#Stringify):

```
{
    local $YAML::Stringify = 1;
    say Dump($data);
}
```

This makes YAML use the stringification overloads from JSON::PP::Boolean instead of dumping object internals.

Comment: Thank you from saving me the hassle of performing a recursive walk on `$data` to massage it with `JSON::is_bool`

Comment: YES! :) It does exactly what i want. Thank you much.

Answer (score 2):

A general solution:

```
use Carp qw( carp );

sub convert_bools {
    my %unrecognized;

    local *_convert_bools = sub {
        my $ref_type = ref($_[0]);
        if (!$ref_type) {
            # Nothing.
        }
        elsif ($ref_type eq 'HASH') {
            _convert_bools($_) for values(%{ $_[0] });
        }
        elsif ($ref_type eq 'ARRAY') {
            _convert_bools($_) for @{ $_[0] };
        }
        elsif (
               $ref_type eq 'JSON::PP::Boolean'           # JSON::PP
            || $ref_type eq 'Types::Serialiser::Boolean'  # JSON::XS
        ) {
            $_[0] = $_[0] ? 1 : 0;
        }
        else {
            ++$unrecognized{$ref_type};
        }
    };

    &_convert_bools;

    carp("Encountered an object of unrecognized type $_")
        for sort values(%unrecognized);
}

my $data = decode_json($json);
convert_bools($data);
```

Comment: Why not just use `JSON::is_bool`?

Comment: @Zaid, I imagine that's fine if you use JSON.pm. However, I never use that module -- it's approach of defaulting to JSON::PP instead of JSON::XS is too error-prone -- and I didn't want to limit my solution to only working with some versions of some JSON modules.

Comment: For example, `JSON::is_bool` won't work in a project that uses both JSON::PP and JSON::XS.

Answer (score 0):

Using [YAML::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::XS) 0.67 or higher, you can do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;
use warnings;

use JSON;
use YAML::XS;

my $json_string = q(
{
   "some" : [
      { "isFlagged" : true, "name" : "Some name" },
      { "isFlagged" : false, "name" : "Some other name" }
   ]
}
);

my $data = decode_json($json_string);
local $YAML::XS::Boolean = 'JSON::PP';
say Dump($data);
```